# xml file root.iter() and for loop output different results

Tags: xml

I'm confused why the following two commands output different results:

```
root = gml.getroot()  # define an element tree
for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

This will output the following contents in my .xml file:

```
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
...
```

However, this code with `root.iter()` will output different results...

```
for elem in root.iter():
    print(elem.tag, elem.attrib)
```

which returns

```
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}CityModel {'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation': 'http://www.opengis.net/citygml/cityobjectgroup/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/cityobjectgroup/2.0/cityObjectGroup.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0/building.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/tunnel/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/tunnel/2.0/tunnel.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/waterbody/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/waterbody/2.0/waterBody.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/appearance/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/appearance/2.0/appearance.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/cityfurniture/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/cityfurniture/2.0/cityFurniture.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0/generics.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/bridge/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/bridge/2.0/bridge.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/vegetation/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/vegetation/2.0/vegetation.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/transportation/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/transportation/2.0/transportation.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/relief/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/relief/2.0/relief.xsd http://www.opengis.net/citygml/landuse/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/citygml/landuse/2.0/landUse.xsd'}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0}Building {'{http://www.opengis.net/gml}id': 'UUID_82d7797e-7082-4d1c-a2e1-95f566b8f692'}
{http://www.opengis.net/gml}boundedBy {}
{http://www.opengis.net/gml}Envelope {'srsName': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326', 'srsDimension': '3'}
{http://www.opengis.net/gml}lowerCorner {}
{http://www.opengis.net/gml}upperCorner {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}creationDate {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}externalReference {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}informationSystem {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}externalObject {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}name {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}externalReference {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}informationSystem {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}externalObject {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}name {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}intAttribute {'name': 'Region'}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}value {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}intAttribute {'name': 'QualitaetStatus'}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}value {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}stringAttribute {'name': 'Herkunft'}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}value {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}intAttribute {'name': 'GebaeudeStatus'}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}value {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}dateAttribute {'name': 'FileCreationDate'}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}value {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0}class {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0}consistsOfBuildingPart {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0}BuildingPart {'{http://www.opengis.net/gml}id': 'UUID_9c7467b2-96ab-4844-af76-95eeddc6c8d7'}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}creationDate {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}intAttribute {'name': 'Geomtype'}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/generics/2.0}value {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0}boundedBy {}
{http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0}WallSurface {'{http://www.opengis.net/gml}id': 'UUID_9f8df737-fe84-451c-aad9-803faaea66d2'}
...
```

Seems that `root.iter()` will loop over **every** child and sub-child in the tree, while the `for` loop will only loop over immediate child?

I'm also having trouble searching for explanations for these two functionalities. How can I refer to their different behaviors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the spamming, I just found [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) on `Element.iter()` and indeed "the iterator iterates over this element and all elements below it, in document (depth first) order. " Guess my confusion is mainly caused by the similar API names.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is the documentation on `for` loop usage, section 19.7.1.2.